# Field List Is Greyed Out in PivotTable

Tags: excel, vba

Somehow the Field List for the pivot table is greyed out. I don't know what part of the process 
made this happened.

I've tried the following:

`Application.CommandBars("PivotTable Field List").Enabled = True`
`ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True`

one that has issued
[image: one that has issued]

correct one
[image: correct one]

has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Do you have any duplicate custom field names?

Comment: @MarkS. Let me check. Sorry for not getting you back ASAP.

Comment: @MarkS. I do have the same column header in two different tables. After I changed, it still has the same issue. I guess it's a coincidence.

Comment: Column Headers <> Custom Field Names. The Custom Field name are calculations done within the pivot outside of the table range. Having this duplicate can cause issues when referring to it in the VBA.